# Left ideals contain a non-zero idempotent

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, idempotents

Let $D$ be a division ring and $S$ a subring of $D$ containing $1$. 
 Define

$$R(D,S)=\{ (x_1, x_2, \dots,x_n, s, s, \dots)\vert n \geq 1, x_i \in D, s \in S\} $$

and say that every nonzero left (right) ideal of $R$ contains a non-zero idempotent.

I know that the ideals of $D$ are $D$ and $\{0\}$, but I don't know how to find the ideals of $R$.

Comment: Addition and multiplication are pointwise , I guess? You really ought to mention it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $I$ be a non-zero left ideal of $R(D,S)$. Let $(x_{1},x_{2},\ldots,x_{n},s,s,\ldots)$ be a non-zero element in $I$. Then some entry of the vector is non-zero. If one of $x_{i}$'s is non-zero, say $x_{j}\neq 0$, then 
$$(0,\ldots,0,x_{j}^{-1},0,0,\ldots)(x_{1},\ldots,x_{n},s,s,\ldots)=(0,\ldots,0,1,0,0,\ldots)$$
is a non-zero idempotent in $I$, where $x_{j}^{-1}$ and $1$ are the $j$-th entry. 
If all $x_{i}$'s are zero, then $s\neq 0$. So 
$$(0,\ldots,0,s^{-1},0,0,\ldots)(x_{1},x_{2},\ldots,x_{n},s,s,\ldots)=(0,\ldots,0,1,0,0,\ldots)$$ is a non-zero idempotent in $I$, where the $s^{-1}$ and $1$ are the $(n+1)$-th entry.

Comment: Sorry, I made an earlier comment based on the misreading that $n$ is fixed, but that didn’t sound right and I checked myself.

Comment: I can think of $s^{-1}$ as one of the $x_{i}$'s. That is a good point. I also was not sure about whether $n$ is fixed.

Comment: if n was fixed there’d be no point in the infinite tails!